# Adding of numeric values in Html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Well i was trying to create a simple calculator using HTMl, JS and JQuery ,
I created two  text box for input of numbers but ,
I am not able to add the given numeric values in the input box , it always concatenate the values . Please Help Me .

Comment: What do you mean. can you setup a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you read the values from your input boxes, you are reading them as strings.  unfortuneately for javascript & math, the + symbol means two different things (in math it means add, in js is means concatentate, and, well add sometimes too).

You need to cast your strings as ints ( or floats or whatever) and then add them in javascript.  you can do that this way:

```
var intstr0 = "1";
var intstr1 = "2";

var sum  = parseInt(intstr0) + parseInt(intstr1);
```

Comment: You should specify a radix: `parseInt(intstr0, 10)`

Comment: _If_ you use `parseInt()` you should specify a radix as per Blender's suggestion, but why would you use `parseInt()` at all? The user might enter `"1.7"`.

Answer (score 1):

Input boxes values' will be strings, and not numbers.  To convert that input box to a number, try [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) or [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) around the values.  Then, you can add them with `+`.